# Multiple NSPredicate on NSArray

Tags: ios

I have an array of `NSPredicate` and an array of values. Now, I want to search if all the `NSPredicate` are `true` for this array. I am using a loop for it like this:

```
bool valid = true;
for(NSPredicate* predicate in predicates){
                if([[searchValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] count] == 0){
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Is there a better way to do this meaning somehow avoiding the loop on NSPredicate?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *predicates = ... // your array of predicates
NSPredicate *andPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
BOOL valid = [[searchValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:andPredicate] count] > 0;
```

Comment: No, this is not what I intend to do. Here the compound predicate should be true for each value while I want that each predicate should be satisfied by at least one data value. See the above code.

Comment: @Aarkan: Your are right, I misunderstood the question, sorry. - I do not think that there is a better or easier way than looping over the predicates as you did.